# What pattern can I use to avoid instancing unnecessary blocks from pipeline?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, instance, pipeline

My ASP.NET Core application is using our self-designed pipelines to process requests. Every pipeline contains 1+ blocks, and the number of blocks have no any limit. it can be up to 200+ blocks in real instance, the pipeline will go through all blocks by a sequence from a configuration, like:

```
Pipeline<DoActionsPipeline>().AddBlock<DoActionAddUserBlock>().AddBlock<DoActionAddUserToRoleBlock>()...
```

Like above example(just an example), and there are 200+ blocks configured in this pipeline, the blocks could be `DoActionAddUserBlock`, `DoActionAddUserToRoleBlock`, `DoActionAddAddressToUserBlock`, and so on. many actions are mixed in one pipeline. (Please don't ask why mix them, it's just an example, it doesn't matter to my question.)

For this example, in each block, we will check the action name first, if match, then run logics. but this is pretty bad, it has to instance all blocks and go throgh all of them to get a request done.

Here is sample code, not very good, but it shows my pain:

```
public class DoActionAddUserBlock : BaseBlock<User, User, Context>
{
    public override User Execute(User arg, Context context)
    {
        if (context.ActionName != "AddUser")
        {
            return arg;
        }

        return AddUser(arg);
    }

    protected User AddUser(User user)
    {
        return user;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseBlock<TArg, TResult, TContext>
{
    public abstract TResult Execute(TArg arg, TContext context);
}

public class Context
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
public class User
{

}
```

I want to avoid instancing blocks by conditions, I think it should be in pipeline-configuration level. how can I reach this? Attributes? or something others.

```
[Condition("Action==AddUser")] // or [Action("AddUser")] // or [TypeOfArg("User")]
public class DoActionAddUserBlock : BaseBlock<User, User, Context>
{
    public override User Execute(User arg, Context context)
    {
        return AddUser(arg);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: What about a lock?

Comment: What is the source of the action name, where does it come from? Nonetheless of your answer, this sounds like an AB problem. You would be better off building a service and using routings.

Comment: @modiX yes, we have routing and service exactly. but they all will call pipelines. and they are called by arguments, for this example specificly, the argument contains a property: ActionName. the blocks can be re-used here and there in different pipelines by configuration.

Comment: A pipeline maps nicely to the functional paradigm. If you can manage to keep your functions pure, i.e. your Blocks mapping TArg and TContext to TResult without any other state of their own. Then you can create DI singleton instances of your Blocks, creating them only once when you launch server side.

Comment: @Funk no, Singleton does not work here. Blocks will be referenced in different pipelines by configurations, they have to work for different context and data. but conditions are always same, I mean the logics.

Comment: Seems to me that it should work in your use case... If your blocks are merely converters, with no state of their own (i.e. have _only local variables_ in the Execute method), without producing side effects, and solely convert arg and context to result. Then you should be able to add the same instance to all pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

**Please show us the `Pipeline<T>()` method (is a method or a class?), because it's essential for an accurate answer.**

Anyway i want to try my best with the current infos.

Your goal is *"i want to conditionally instance blocks"*, so you have to move your condition in a out-of-instance context, something you can do with attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ActionNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ActionNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

[ActionName(nameof(AddUser))]
public class DoActionAddUserBlock : BaseBlock<User, User, Context>
{
    public override User Execute(User arg, Context context)
    {
        return AddUser(arg);
    }
}
```

Then, do the check into the `.AddBlock<T>()` method (that, i guess, is something like that):

```
public YourUnknownType<T> AddBlock<TBlock>()
{
    var type = typeof(TBlock);
    var attributes = attributes.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionNameAttribute), inherit: true); // or false if you don't need inheritation
    var attribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault() as ActionNameAttribute;

    if (attribute.Name == this.Context.ActioName)
    {
        // place here the block init
    }

    return AnythingYouActuallyReturn();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pipeline manages its block sequence to run, AddBlock<> is just the block to sequence, the logic should be in pipeline level, not inside of blocks. Attributes are hard-coded and compiled, how can it read arg or context at runtime? is there a delegate method that can calculate conditions by hard-coded method and work at runtime.

Comment: I can't help you more without an example of your Pipeline<T> class/method.
There is a lot of possible implementations that can be adopted, but the right one is straightly related to your code.

Answer (score 0):

IMO
you should define different pipelines for different usage. That's a design pattern that should be used only for some particular cases. Maybe it is not good pattern in your case?

I think that it shouldn't be in pipeline responsibility to check the action name and MAYBE run logic. If you define a pipeline for some logic it should just "go with the flow".

Therefore, pipelines should be build once on project startup and initializing whole pipeline just once is good.

Please think about if using pipelines is good in your scenario.

I've built a simple pipeline with builder and steps you can check it [here](https://devonboard.wordpress.com/2019/09/18/pipeline-pipes-filters/). It's in polish but all the code is in English so you might get the point.

Comment: Yes, this pattern go through everywhere in our product. and your simple pipeline is actually same idea as ours. Can you please share your code somewhere? so we can talk more efficiently? I want do something based on yours. Thanks a lot.